# Applying filter and paginaton on different micro services

Tags: java, database, pagination, microservices

There are two microservices. One for Account service, other for customer service.

 
**Account service** stores the data such as account id, customer id, account balance, interest earned and other monetary stuff.

**Customer service** has personal data such as an customer id, home address, email id, the frequency for sending emails/alerts, Customer-type(Premium, Gold, Silver)... etc.

**The account has customer id as the foreign key to map the account and customer data.**

The requirement is such that I need to build a search UI **memory-efficient**. Fetch all the accounts which belong to a particular customer type (premium/gold) and have a balance greater than 200$. So if you see there is cross join filter ie filter needs to be applied on both the microservices to get the desired data.  Also, only 10 records would be fetched (page size).On click on the next button, the next 10 records would be fetched.

So how do I fetch the records/store data for this scenario? **This is a sort of design /architecture question. I am not expecting the query syntax or sql syntax or hibernate(ORM) syntax.** 

Should I fetch all the records at the same time, keep it in memory and then apply filters along with pagination. Or Should I use some batching? 

*Also, I won't prefer SQL joins. This create dependency. If database tables get altered, the query will get impacted*

Comment: currently without any filter how do you get data ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Currently, there is no service to fetch both the services data.  There is separate UI to fetch the account balances from the account microservice. Separate UI from fetching customer information. This is a new screen getting designed. So looking for ideas to implement it properly.

Comment: In such cases I would suggest to make 2 different call to get details, this is where you can utilize the microservice architecture.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra problem is how do you make 2 different calls... here the fetching logic is not based on primary key or unique id. You need to fetch all the records, so the problem here is, do we need pagination or some sort of other techniques.